# dell xps water damage - keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, motherboard, dell-xps, water-damage

My daughter spilled a small amount of water on her XPS 13 9360 keyboard a few weeks ago.  The keyboard stopped working the next day.  The backlight comes on, but none of the keys work.  I purchased a new keyboard and did some significant surgery to replace it. Unfortunately, the new keyboard still does not work.  I'm tempted to purchase a [new motherboard](https://www.ebay.com/itm/REAL-DEAL-Dell-XPS-13-9360-Motherboard-i7-7500U-8gb-Intel-HD-Graphics-620-VMMP2/203133221454) (returnable if it doesn't solve the problem). Any other ideas?  Appreciate any advice.  I'm reasonably technical.

Answer (score 0):

Liquid damage is nearly always electrical shorts caused by connected circuits where connect circuits are not supposed to be, and thus components are exposed to currents they are not designed to handle.

Because of this, the portion of the computer that was actually damaged varies widely and wildly and randomly.

To make this more difficult, failing to replace the damaged parts could cause damage to the components that were replaced.

You could end up chasing your tail.

So, if you're willing and able to replace the components one at a time in hopes of resucitating the laptop, go ahead. But just know that it may not be straightforward or easy.